# Get list of programs in system tray in Windows 11

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

How can I get the number of apps in the system tray in Windows 11?

It succeeds on Windows10 but fails on Windows11.

After running the following code on Windows 11, the number of tray apps is zero.

TB_BUTTONCOUNT returns zero.

```
int GetTrayAppCount()
{
    HWND hWndTray   = NULL;
    int  nTrayCount = 0;

    // Hide Tray App
    hWndTray = ::FindWindow( TEXT("NotifyIconOverflowWindow"),NULL );
    if( hWndTray ){
        if((hWndTray = ::FindWindowEx( hWndTray,NULL,TEXT("ToolbarWindow32"),NULL ))){
            nTrayCount += (int)::SendMessage( hWndTray, TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0,0 );
        }
    }

    //  Show Tray App
    hWndTray = ::FindWindow( TEXT("Shell_TrayWnd"),NULL );
    if( hWndTray ){
        hWndTray = ::FindWindowEx( hWndTray,NULL,TEXT("TrayNotifyWnd"),NULL );
        if( hWndTray ){
            hWndTray = ::FindWindowEx( hWndTray,NULL,TEXT("SysPager"),NULL );
            if( hWndTray ){
                hWndTray = ::FindWindowEx( hWndTray,NULL,TEXT("ToolbarWindow32"),NULL );
                nTrayCount += (int)::SendMessage( hWndTray, TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0,0 );
            }
        }
    }
    return nTrayCount;
}
```

Comment: see https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=111398#p499459

Comment: If ever, this used to work out of sheer luck. It relies on implementation details, rather than contractual interfaces. That out of the way, why do you need to know? This isn't questioning your intentions; it is rather an attempt at figuring out what *problem* you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'll question your intentions. This code is relying on private and undocumented information from the OS. Why do you need this kind of code? What are you actually trying to accomplish with it? Most systray apps don't care about other apps' tray icons, only their own, so what is special about your app that it needs to mess around with other apps' tray icons?

Comment: I am developing a screen reader.
Operating the Windows system tray using only the keyboard can be difficult.
The purpos is for blind or visually impaired users to be able to easily operate system tray applications using keyboard-only controls with the help of a screen reader.
@IInspectable

Comment: Assistive technology is implemented over [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: @AlanBirtles I checked the link.
Windows 11 system tray is now a XAML app and toolbar messages don't seem to be available.
It may be possible to use UI Automation to achieve it.

Comment: I used UIAutomation to get a system tray app.
I was able to get the apps that were visible, but not the ones that were not.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you could interact with the app in system tray programmatically once it's visible. You could try to show all icons in system tray in windows11.

Comment: @IInspectable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tb-buttoncount.  I had a script under windows 10 that would check for a third party software update in the overflow tray and update the software if it was there.  This is for IT because the software vendor doesn't offer hooks or an automatic updater.  The end users aren't updating across the hundreds of machines causing issues.  This is broken in windows 11 because these calls are now gone.  If I force the taskbar to be locked and the icon to the taskbar, I can use UI automation.  Then the user can't hide the taskbar.  :(