How to get system tray information in python?
How to traverse the system tray and get the icon information in it?
Such as the icon, the process that created it...
I found a page that meets my requirements, I rewrote its code in Python using ctypes properly.
The Original code is based on Windows 10.
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

# 定义常量
PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008
PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010
PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020
MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40
MEM_RELEASE = 0x00008000
TB_BUTTONCOUNT = 0x0400 + 24
TB_GETBUTTON = 0x0417

# 定义结构体
class SYSTEM_INFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('wProcessorArchitecture', wintypes.WORD),
        ('wReserved', wintypes.WORD),
        ('dwPageSize', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('lpMinimumApplicationAddress', wintypes.LPVOID),
        ('lpMaximumApplicationAddress', wintypes.LPVOID),
        ('dwActiveProcessorMask', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('dwNumberOfProcessors', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('dwProcessorType', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('dwAllocationGranularity', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('wProcessorLevel', wintypes.WORD),
        ('wProcessorRevision', wintypes.WORD)
    ]

class TBBUTTON(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('iBitmap', ctypes.c_int),
        ('idCommand', ctypes.c_int),
        ('fsState', ctypes.c_byte),
        ('fsStyle', ctypes.c_byte),
        ('bReserved', ctypes.c_byte * 6),
        ('dwData', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ('iString', ctypes.c_void_p)
    ]

# 定义函数
def Is64bitSystem():
    si = SYSTEM_INFO()
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetNativeSystemInfo(ctypes.byref(si))
    return si.wProcessorArchitecture in [ctypes.wintypes.WORD(9), ctypes.wintypes.WORD(6)]

def FindTrayWnd():
    hWnd = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW("Shell_TrayWnd", None)
    hWnd = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowExW(hWnd, None, "TrayNotifyWnd", None)
    hWnd = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowExW(hWnd, None, "SysPager", None)
    hWnd = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowExW(hWnd, None, "ToolbarWindow32", None)
    return hWnd

def FindNotifyIconOverflowWindow():
    hWnd = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW("NotifyIconOverflowWindow", None)
    hWnd = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowExW(hWnd, None, "ToolbarWindow32", None)
    return hWnd

def EnumNotifyWindow(hWnd):
    # 获取托盘进程ID
    dwProcessId = wintypes.DWORD()
    ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, ctypes.byref(dwProcessId))
    if dwProcessId.value == 0:
        print("GetWindowThreadProcessId failed:", ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError())
        return False

    # 获取托盘进程句柄
    hProcess = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE, False, dwProcessId)
    if hProcess == 0:
        print("OpenProcess failed:", ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError())
        return False

    # 在进程虚拟空间中分配内存，用来接收 TBBUTTON 结构体指针
    p_tbbutton = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, 4096, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)
    if p_tbbutton == 0:
        print("VirtualAllocEx failed:", ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError())
        return False

    # 初始化
    dw_addr_dwData = 0
    buff = ctypes.create_string_buffer(1024)
    h_mainWnd = None
    i_data_offset = 12
    i_str_offset = 18

    # 判断 x64
    if Is64bitSystem():
        i_data_offset += 4
        i_str_offset += 6

    # 获取托盘图标个数
    i_buttons = ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(hWnd, TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0)
    if i_buttons != 0:
        print("TB_BUTTONCOUNT message failed:", ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError())
        return False
    i_buttons = 2

    # 遍历托盘
    for i in range(i_buttons):
        # 获取 TBBUTTON 结构体指针
        if not ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(hWnd, TB_GETBUTTON, i, p_tbbutton):
            print("TB_GETBUTTON message failed:", ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError())
            return False

        # 读 TBBUTTON.dwData（附加信息）
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, ctypes.c_void_p(p_tbbutton.value + i_data_offset), ctypes.byref(dw_addr_dwData), 4, None)
        if dw_addr_dwData:
            ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, ctypes.c_void_p(dw_addr_dwData), buff, 1024, None)
            h_mainWnd = ctypes.cast(buff.raw[:4], ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.HWND)).contents
            ws_filePath = ctypes.c_wchar_p(buff.raw[i_str_offset:i_str_offset + ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.WCHAR) * ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.MAX_PATH)])
            ws_tile = ctypes.c_wchar_p(buff.raw[i_str_offset + ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.WCHAR) * ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.MAX_PATH):])
            print("hMainWnd =", hex(h_mainWnd.value))
            print("strFilePath =", ws_filePath.value)
            print("strTile =", ws_tile.value)

        # 清理
        dw_addr_dwData = 0
        h_mainWnd = None

        print()

    ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, p_tbbutton, 0, MEM_RELEASE)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(hProcess)

    return True

def main():
    # 解决控制台中文 '？'
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "chs")

    # 获取托盘句柄
    h_tray = FindTrayWnd()
    h_tray_fold = FindNotifyIconOverflowWindow()

    # 遍历托盘窗口
    if not EnumNotifyWindow(h_tray) or not EnumNotifyWindow(h_tray_fold):
        print("EnumNotifyWindow false.")

    input()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


However, it doesn't work on Windows 11...
On the code, line 92, I found that the variable of "i_buttons" are always 0.
I don't want to use ANY large library(such as PyQt) to complete my problem, thank you.

closely linked to https://stackoverflow.com/q/75983665/14862885 just doing c things in python

Check [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer) for a common pitfall when working with CTypes (calling functions).

Note dwActiveProcessorMask is defined as DWORD_PTR, which is 64-bit on 64-bit Windows.  wintypes.DWORD is only 32-bit.  Define DWORD_PTR = ctypes.c_size_t because that type is unsigned 32-/64-bit depending on OS and use that.

You can consider pywinauto it is not a large library like tk:
Here is code to recursively traverse
from pywinauto import Desktop


def print_window_tree(window, level=0):
    indent = "  " * level 
    print(f"{indent}Level {level}: {window.window_text()}, Handle: {window.handle}, Class Name: {window.class_name()}")
    

    children = window.children()
    for child in children:
        print_window_tree(child, level + 1)


window = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Taskbar")
print_window_tree(window)

here is my output:
Level 0: Taskbar, Handle: 131226, Class Name: Shell_TrayWnd
  Level 1: , Handle: 131208, Class Name: TrayNotifyWnd
  Level 1: , Handle: 66140, Class Name: Windows.UI.Input.InputSite.WindowClass
    Level 2: , Handle: None, Class Name: Taskbar.TaskbarFrameAutomationPeer
      Level 3: Start, Handle: None, Class Name: ToggleButton
      Level 3: Search, Handle: None, Class Name: ToggleButton
        Level 4: Search, Handle: None, Class Name: TextBlock
        Level 4: Search - Winter travel planning, Handle: None, Class Name: Button
        Level 4: , Handle: None, Class Name: Image
      Level 3: Task View, Handle: None, Class Name: ToggleButton
      ------open applications------
    --the below is systray items--
    Level 2: Show Hidden Icons, Handle: None, Class Name: SystemTray.NormalButton
    Level 2:  OneDrive - Personal

Your OneDrive is 92% full, Handle: None, Class Name: SystemTray.NormalButton
      Level 3: , Handle: None, Class Name: Image
    Level 2: Windows Security - Actions recommended. Windows Security - No actions needed., Handle: None, Class Name: SystemTray.NormalButton
      Level 3: , Handle: None, Class Name: Image
    Level 2: Tray Input Indicator English (United States)

English (India)



To switch input methods, press Windows key + space., Handle: None, Class Name: SystemTray.NormalButton
    Level 2: Network HOME 2.4GHz
Internet access, Handle: None, Class Name: SystemTray.AccentButton
    Level 2: Volume Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio): 100%, Handle: None, Class Name: SystemTray.OmniButtonRight
    Level 2: Clock 08:37 PM
‎24.‎11.‎24, Handle: None, Class Name: SystemTray.OmniButtonLeft
    Level 2: Notifications 5 new notifications, Handle: None, Class Name: SystemTray.AccentButton
    Level 2: Show Desktop, Handle: None, Class Name: SystemTray.ShowDesktopButton

(nothing personal)
you can get required info in level 2
The key is to use uia backend: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32 instead of win32

I tried that, but may it isn't work in Windows11.
In Windows 11, the icon on the system tray is not a separate window.
This means that we can't get the information by traversing the window.

well i am using windows 11 and it works, have you tried running this,what was the output?, ik sys tray is not a window and now UI automation is being used, i have used that too, traversing the window with handle you cant get anything, as handle is meant only for larger elements like the taskbar itself. notice that in my output, items of level 2 are sys tray items, who have handle None?

however you can transverse through it. note that i dont mean everything like systray  is window in the o/p tree, only top few levels are window's, but you can get it's children which aren't window by using window.children()

There is my output.
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
File "D:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Desktop\Desktop.py", line 15, in 
print_window_tree(window)
File "d:\Desktop\Desktop.py", line 6, in print_window_tree
print(...)
...
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Taskbar', 'top_level_only': True, 'backend': 'uia'}

Sorry I am not getting why this doesn't work you can see my pc's output I am not getting why this doesn't work for you.

@hite404 saw something very useful for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects !!

You can provide your output like mine(after using follow mouse and clicking taskbar), mine has the window taskbar: https://i.ibb.co/t4rbtcp/image.png
